# Why does my webapp.sh not run and disk not attach to my GCP instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create a GCP instance with a boot disk and an extra disk also trying to install some packages using a shell script file.

I have tried a **file** provisioner to transfer the file to instance but it's not working (there is a timeout error). The additional disk is also not attaching to the instance.

When I remove the  provisioner, the infrastructure setup works fine and the additional disk attaches to the instance.

**main.tf**

```
data "google_compute_zones" "available" {
  region  = var.gcp_region
  project = var.gcp_project
}

#Create boot disk
resource "google_compute_disk" "os-disk" {
  name   = format("os-disk-%s", var.instance_name)
  type   = "pd-ssd"
  image  = var.image
  size   = var.os_pd_ssd_size
  zone   = "us-central1-c"
}

#Create attached disk to instance size 30 GB
resource "google_compute_disk" "test-disk" {
  name   = format("test-disk-%s", var.instance_name)
  type   = "pd-ssd"
  size   = var.test_pd_ssd_size
  zone   = "us-central1-c"
}

#Main test instance
resource "google_compute_instance" "test" {
  name         = var.instance_name
  machine_type = var.machine_type
  tags = ["http-server", "https-server"]
  zone         = "us-central1-c"

  boot_disk {
    source = google_compute_disk.os-disk.name
    auto_delete = false
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"

    access_config {
      // Ephemeral IP
    }
  }


  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [attached_disk]
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "./scripts/webapp.sh"
    destination = "/home/webapp.sh"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "chmod +x /home/webapp.sh",
      "./webapp.sh",
    ]
  }

}

#Attached additional disk to instance 
resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "default" {
  disk     = google_compute_disk.test-disk.id
  instance = google_compute_instance.test.id
}
```

The additional disk is not attaching and webapp.sh is also not transferring to or executing on the instance.

Why does my webapp.sh not run and disk not attach to my GCP instance?

Comment: I thought I'd try and recreate .. but it looks like I need your variables and files.

Comment: @Kolban Hi there thanks a lot for that but it sarted working now. i will update the status of question. thankyou so much again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a **file** or **remote-exec** provisioner, you can just directly execute **webapp.sh** on the instance with **metadata_startup_script** as follows:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "test" {
  name         = var.instance_name
  machine_type = var.machine_type
  tags = ["http-server", "https-server"]
  zone         = "us-central1-c"

  boot_disk {
    source = google_compute_disk.os-disk.name
    auto_delete = false
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"

    access_config {
      // Ephemeral IP
    }
  }


  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [attached_disk]
  }

  metadata_startup_script = file("${path.module}/scripts/webapp.sh")

}
```

OS-level issues like mounting volumes are not solved by Terraform. When you attach an additional disk, it attaches as hardware, not in the OS configuration. It's like attaching an additional disk to via SATA inside your computer tower. You have to **mount** that disk in the OS of the instance explicitly for it to be recognized.

Read more about mounting zonal persistent disks in GCP here:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk

Comment: thanks a lot for answer got your point probably i have to update some changes. thanks again